# Datagrid binding to a list based on a value of a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

The datagrid is databound to List.

```
class Channel
{

  string Name;
  string id;
  customEnum val;
}
```

where

```
  Enum CustomEnum {All=0,TypeA, TypeB }
```

Now based on the selection from a combobox i want to display in the grid.Suppose the combobox selected value is TypeA. Only they have to be displayed in the grid. others has to be removed/hid. How do i do that? Also the first column in the grid displayed is index of the row. I have added id to keep the index(i used to generate the index based on the item index in the list). Since the rows will be changed on selection of the combobox how do i show the index now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) , and use the Filter option for the ICollection